# $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:[0,1] \to \Bbb C - \{0\}$ are closed paths and have the same index

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:[0,1] \to \Bbb C - \{0\}$ are closed paths and have the same index ( or winding number) around $0$ , then they are homotopic.

So, I think I have an idea on how to show it:

we have $g_1,g_2:[0,1] \to \Bbb C$ continuous logarithms for $\gamma_1 , \gamma_2$ , that is $\gamma_i (t) = e \ ^ {g_i (t) } $ for $i=1,2$.

So it is enough to show that $g_1,g_2$ homotopic.

It seems easy to show that because $\Bbb C$ is convex, so i thought the homotopy would be :

$H(s,t) = (1-s) g_1(t) + sg_2(t)$

We need to show that $H(0,t) = \gamma_1(t) , H(1,t) = \gamma_2(t) $
 (which is easy) and that $H(s,0) = H(s,1) $ . to show this :

Suppose $k= n(\gamma_i , 0)$ is the index of the paths then we know that $k = \dfrac{g_i(1) - g_i(0)}{2\pi i}$
So $2\pi i k = g_1(1) - g_1(0) = g_0(1) - g_0(0)$

So $H(s,0) = H(s,1) $ iff $2 \pi i k = 0$ , and this is not required in the question.

What am I missing ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Where does $k$ enter your proof?

Comment: @eranreches i edited the question

Comment: @Liad, the main issue you have with your suggestion is keeping it within the domain $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$. See my answer as to how to avoid this.

Comment: @Mariah i wrote an homotopy beween $g_i : [0,1] \to \Bbb C$ so there isn't a problem with $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $H(s,t) = \exp\Big((1-s)g_1(t) + sg_2(t)\Big)$. I think this, with the assumption of the same winding number should solve it.

More info:

$Im(H) \subset \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$, this is obvious.

Set $s \in [0,1]$. Then $H(s,0) = exp(g_1(0))exp(s[g_2(0) - g_1(0)]) = exp(g_1(1))exp(s[g_2(1) - g_1(1)]) =  H(s,1)$ where the second equality is due to the paths being closed, $g_1$ being a logaritm, and the same winding number around  $0$.

The fact that $H(0,t) = \gamma_1$, $H(1,t) = \gamma_2$ is obvious.

This is then a homotopy in the wanted domain.

This gives a direct homotopy between the paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$. Using the exponential in the homotopy will result in a closed loop for all $s$ (use the assumption of the same winding number), which doesn't pass through $0$ (as opposed to not using the exponential as you did in your attempt).

Comment: corrected, should have $g$ within the exponential.

Comment: You're not answering the question, because that's exactly what the OP have done so far.

Comment: @eranreches not it isn't.. wow with the down votes.. work it out, I think it's fine. He has the homotopy not using the exponential at all.

Comment: The homotopy I wrote will close any loop on $s$, and is continuous..

Comment: @Mariah He doesn't use the exponential because he looks at the continuous **logarithm** of the curves. Your answer is essentially correct, but you should explain that your homotopy is a direct one between the $\gamma$'s, and not between the $g$'s (logarithms) as the OP tries to do. After you do that I'd upvote.

Comment: @eranreches edited. I do accept your suggestion. I do not understand how a correct answer can result in two immediate down votes.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for every $s$, the function $H\left(s,\cdot\right):\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ should also map under $\exp$ to a closed path with index $k$. Ergo, exactly as with the $g$'s

$$\frac{H\left(s,1\right)-H\left(s,0\right)}{2\pi i}=k$$

is the winding number of the path $\exp\Big(H\left(s,\cdot\right)\Big):\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$. Therefore, by requiring

$$H\left(s,1\right)=H\left(s,0\right)$$

you are unintentionally demanding that $k=0$.

Comment: $g_i :[0,1] \to \Bbb C$ so why should i show $H$ does not cross the orgin?

Comment: also the requiring $H(s,1) = H(s,0) $ is a requirement for path homotopoy.. and your homotopoy does not satisfy this.

Comment: @Liad My mistake. I've thought about $\gamma$'s instead of $g$'s. Anyway, I've edited my answer. As for your second comment, this is the requirement for homotopy of **closed paths**, but the $g$'s are not close at all.

Comment: the codomain of $H$ should be $\Bbb C$ doesnt it?

Comment: @Liad Problem fixed.

Comment: i dont understand if we just want homotopy(not of closed paths) then we dont need to even check $H(s,1) , H(s,0)$ just that $H(0,t) = g_1, H(1,t) =g_2$ , what am i missing?

Comment: @Liad Look for example at the continuous logarithm of two circles of radii $r_{1,2}$ receptively. You have $$g_{1}\left(t\right)=\ln r_{1}+2\pi it$$ $$g_{2}\left(t\right)=\ln r_{2}+2\pi it$$ for $t\in\left[0,1\right]$. These are two lines parallel to the imaginary axis. Your homotopy $H$ should just move one line to the other continuously without maintaining endpoints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70280/discussion-between-liad-and-eranreches).